PCA factor model - insignificant factor loadings
I have a time-series of N assets for which I am trying to estimate a factor model. Let $Z_{t}$ be one of these assets' prices at time $t$. We can write it as:
$$
Z_{t} = \beta F_{t} + \theta_{t}
$$
where $F_{t}$ is some linear factor and $\theta_{t} = \alpha + \epsilon_{t}$, $\epsilon_{t}$ being some white noise with covariance $\Sigma_{\theta}$
With these assumptions, we can write the expected value of $Z_{t}$ as:
$$
\mu_{z} = \alpha + \beta \mu_{F}
$$
And the covariance matrix:
$$
\Sigma_{z} = \beta\Sigma_{\theta}\beta^{T} + \Sigma_{\theta}
$$
The idea is that we have significantly reduced the number of parameters (especially in the covariance) needed to be estimated and therefore (hopefully) estimated a less noisy mean and covariance.
If there is some portfolio of stocks, with portfolio weights $\mathbb{x}$, we can then write the portfolio mean as $\mu_{p} = \mathbb{b}\mu_{F}$, where $\mathbb{b} = \beta^{T}\mathbb{x}$ and the portfolio covariance as $\mathbb{b}^{T}\Sigma_{F}\mathbb{b} + \mathbb{x}^{T}\Sigma_{\theta}\mathbb{x}$.
I have chosen as the factor model SVD analysis on the demeaned data matrix (it can be shown that this is equivalent as performing PCA on the covariance). This is very handy since the covariance matrix $\Sigma_{F}$ is diagonal with the squared eigenvalues. Once I obtained the PCs, my $F_{t}$, I am estimating the $\beta$ parameters by OLS (however, I tried some other methods like iteratively reweighted least squares as well). However, in the diagnostic analysis I can see that the parameters are insignificant. I am a bit perplexed by this. On one hand, I understand this as just a linear algebra method, i.e., least squares as simply a nummerical method for finding the factors, then significance should not matter (unlike a regression in the inferential sense). Even so, if my parameters are close to zero (insignificant), then my factors aren't really .. factorizing .. properly.
Can someone explain this result to me?

Could you explain in more detail how you obtained $F_t$ and what it's dimension is. Also, if this type of factor model is documented somewhere, can you let me know where ? I've always been thinking that factor models could have value but I've never  made one ( I did work with Barra factor models many years ago ) so I'm interested in $F_t$. Unfortunately, that doesn't really help you with your question. Thanks.

Oh, the reason I asked for more details is that, atleast in quant finance, there are many different kinds of factor models so I don't know how to map it to what is discussed in that  literature. I do know what PCA is. thanks.

$F_{t} = XV_{k}^{T}$ where $X$ is the data matrix, say, $(T,N)$ dimensions and $V$ is $(K,N)$ dimensions, with $K$ indicating the number of compononents you would like to keep; if $K=N$ you will reconstruct the data, so to lower dimensions $K < N$.

Hi: Thanks for the explanation. $k$ is the number of components you are keeping so $V_{k}$ must be the matrix of principal components. Therefore, $F_t$ is $T \times k$. Is that correct ? What is the dimension of $\beta$ ?

$\beta$ should be $(N,k)$ and it the in the linear model if should actually be transposed, $F_{t}\beta^{T}$ such that you end up with $X$ being $(T,N)$

okay. I would fix it in the question because, when dimensions don't match, people often stop reading and don't want to bother figuring out what's going on. Now, I'm good and can read it and think about it. I can't guaranteee that I can say something useful. Thanks.

I understand what you're doing now but I can't answer your question. What I came away with by glancing at the literature is that the estimation of this sort of thing is non-trivial and there are various ways to even set up a factor model. Of course, there are many descriptions of the factor model model on the net but this one looked useful at a glance.  I've never read it and it would take me more time than I have at the moment. good luck. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1635495

Thanks for taking your time though. I will have a look at this paper.

No problem, I hope it helps. What you are doing is non-trivial for sure. I wouldn't expect it to just "work" on a first try. There is obviously a lot of literature on factor models but atillio's paper looked useful at a quick glance. Good luck.
